# Bash - copy string in position X to end of line

Tags: bash, sed, cygwin

let's say I have the following text in a file called letters.txt:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
```

And i want to copy position `2-3 (BC)` to end of the line, like this:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTBC
```

I have tried to replace \n with the position 2-3 plus\n but it doesn't work. Example:

```
sed -r "~ s/\n/\^(.{1})(.{2})\n/" letters.txt > letters_new.txt
```

How can i do it using bash? I have searched for an answer but cannot find any.

Comment: you could use a regexp matching line start (`^`) and append the match group containing chars at position 2-3 to the end of line using `echo`. The regexp would be something like `^.(.{2})` (match line start, any char, then any two following chars). You could even simply use `cut -c 2-3` to get the two chars.

Answer (score 2):

```
TEXT=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTBC
echo $TEXT${TEXT:1:2}
```

The secret sauce of bash is described in the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html), here is its [String section](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Comment: The OP wants a **copy** of chars at positions 2 - 3 to be appended to the end of the string. So, it should actually be `$TEXT${TEXT:1:2}`.

Comment: +1 for using the correct technique. I edited the details to match the spec.

Comment: Incidentally, to apply it to a file, use `while read TEXT; do echo "${TEXT}${TEXT:1:2}"; done < letters.txt`

Comment: ams torrentialcoding, thanks! Did a tiny style related update

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you:

```
echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST" | sed 's/.\{1\}\(.\{2\}\).*/&\1/'
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTBC
```

or more simply:

```
echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST" | sed 's/.\(..\).*/&\1/'
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTBC
```